# XPATH to get the displayed label of an input

Tags: xpath

given this:

```
<span data-v-086f077a="" data-v-bf29e118="" class="toggle undefined-undefined small">
<span data-v-086f077a="" class="toggle-label"></span>
<input data-v-086f077a="" type="checkbox" id="tracked-item-toggle-0">
<label data-v-086f077a="" for="tracked-item-toggle-0"><span data-v-086f077a="" class="on-text">Tracked</span>
<span data-v-086f077a="" class="off-text">Not Tracked</span>
</label>
</span>
```

How can I get the displayed text of the input checkbox.
clicking on the checkbox toggles it back and forth and displays either Tracked or Not Tracked. I just need to know which one it is so I can toggle it to Tracked if its Not Tracked.
To toggle I use //span[@class='toggle undefined-undefined small']

I have tried many things including //label[@for='tracked-item-toggle-0' and ./span[contains(.,'Not Tracked')]]
but that finds it whether its displayed or not.

None of the code changes based on toggling the checkbox

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the link to that page so will be able to clearly see how are changing elements attributes to indicate the checked / unchecked state?

Comment: unfortunately not since it would give access to my financial data.
here are 2 pictures though.
https://www.screencast.com/t/zof9YUyg
https://www.screencast.com/t/NpTiAtdEuo

Comment: These pictures are absolutely useless. We need to see the elements with their attributes

Answer (score 2):

The `label` contains two spans which contain the text `Tracked` and `Not Tracked` and have `class` attributes `on-text` and `off-text`, respectively. Which of the two labels is displayed is presumably controlled by CSS.

My guess would be that there are CSS rules which control the `display` or `visibility` properties of these two spans, presumably using their `class` attributes in conjunction with some other attribute of the parent element.

Maybe take a look at the CSS (and include it in your question) and see what it reveals?

Comment: it probably is using some css to do it but if that is true, how could I possibly detect that text with an xpath?

Comment: Presumably the CSS is triggered by _some_ feature of the document. An attribute on some ancestor element? An XPath can detect that same feature that the CSS does. But you have to look at the CSS to see what that feature might be.

Comment: Search the CSS for `.off-text` and `.on-text` and post the rules which you find.